# How to make sails.js socket.io work with ProtoBuf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js, protocol-buffers

Sails' [socket.io support](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub) is pretty good.

I wonder if there is any possibility to intercept socket requests/responses (on both client and server) and encode messages to corresponding protocol buffers message types?

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to be transparent? Dont know if that is possible,, or even makes sence. Protobuf does not care how it is sent, stored etc. So you can pass Message payload to the decoder in protobuf.js and then continue from there with the received data.

Comment: I mean say I have socket.io message named "user" and a user.proto description, so to write an interceptor that will try to find .proto file mached by message name  to decode it (yes) transparently and return the decoded result to a controller.
Say for HTTP front I can use Angular $http-intersceptor, for backend I can use a middleware, and what can I do for socket.io (sails-io)?

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with sails so I cant say. Try asking the folks on [#sailsjs on irc.freenode.net](http://sailsjs.org/support/about-irc)

Comment: No luck getting answer there. But thanks anyway...